In which paper Noether proved her famous theorem in invariant theory?
I looked at mathscinet, zbmath and many books on invariant theory, but I am having some difficulties to find out precisely in which paper(s) Emmy Noether proved the following theorem: If $A$ is a finitely generated associative commutative algebra over a field $k$ and $G$ is a finite group of $k$-algebra automorphisms of $A$, then $A^G$ is also finitely generated, and moreover $A$ is a finitely generated $A^G$-module.

I don't know where the last part ($A$ being a finite $A^G$-module) has been stated explicitly for the first time, but it seems that it could have easily been "folklore" / deemed obvious at the time. My reasoning being that (1) it is clear that $A$ is of finite type over $A^G$ and (2) the proof of the integrality of $A$ over $A^G$ is a one-liner. So, the last statement boils down to whether the "formula" algebra-finite + integral = module-finite was well-known back then. That I don't know - that's for historians of commutative algebra to say :-), but if I had to guess, I'd say "very likely".

The paper, where Emmy Noether proves that $A^G$ is finitely generated, is
Noether, E. "Der Endlichkeitssatz der Invarianten endlicher Gruppen", Math. Ann. Vol.77 (1915), pp. 89-92.
Here is a link to the original article (in German, of course): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01456821
However, I don't know where the last part ($A$ being f.g. $A^G$-module) was stated explicitly for the first time, see may comment above.
